# Program not working after setting script in init.d

Tags: startup, syslog, sysvinit, syslog-ng

I have two programs that need to run on start up. I am using init.d scripts because the virtual machine in my system does not have systemctl. With my configuration program_A is working but program_B is not. It seems it is started but it is not working properly as it not logging in syslog as expected.

My setup is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/Program_A
/usr/bin/Program_B
...
/etc/init.d/Program_A.sh
/etc/init.d/Program_B.sh
```

Where Program_A.sh and Program_B.sh are like

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/Program_A &
disown
```

After creating the init files and copying the executables I have runned

```
update-rc.d Program_A.sh defaults
update-rc.d Program_B.sh defaults
```

**Note 1**: I had to add the "&" and the "disown" in my script because if I didn't the program_A would get stuck and didn't let program_B start

**Note 2**: Both programs are known to be working if executed as:

```
sudo /usr/bin/Program_X
```

**Note 3**
I have removed the "disown" and only launched program_B. It is still not working. **There is a different behaviour between running the script in init.d and how it is launched on startup**.

I can check that the program is launched by :

```
ps -aux | grep Program_B                      
root      1905  0.0  0.2   2308   868 ?        S    09:13   0:00 
/usr/bin/Program_B
```

However, it is not updating a file in syslog. Therefore, it is not running or the program is launched with another name, making the syslog filter not working.

Comment: Does `/etc/init.d/Program_X.sh` both work when run directly ?

Comment: Yes, both work. However, I have to run them as sudo

Comment: I wonder if the `disown` is not having some border effect. Did you try somehow changing the order of the scripts (run B before A) and see what's going on ?

Comment: I have removed disown and only run Program_B (removing everthing related to program_A). Program_B is still not working, However, there is a proces with the name Program_B. I have update the question with more info on NOTE 3

Comment: if Program_B is showing in `ps -aux` then it's running. Not finding it in the syslog may be an unrelated issue (I mean it's a problem with the progam not doing what it is supposed to do, but it is running). Also I wonder why you added the `sudo` in the `init.d` file. I think [it runs automatically as root](https://askubuntu.com/q/290099/621864)

Comment: @dev93 you are correct, removing sudo makes no difference. I have created another question more focused on syslog. Will report here after I find what is happening.